# Can I get a trace of the complexity of a convergent sum?

Tags: functions

*Motivation--- I have a glimmer of an idea that a convergent sum could be considered a self-referential number similar to a fractal.  I would like to play with it for a while.*

I have the following convergent sum:

```
NSum[((1/Pochhammer[m^2 + 1, m]) + (1/Pochhammer[m^2 + m + 1, 2 m])),
  {m, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

Is there a way to show the internals of about 4 or 5 steps?

Comment: I had a big brain-cramp on this question, since I used _trace_ in the title.  Oops!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try `//Trace` option. Can be called as `Trace[command]` also.

Some functions also support an option called `TraceInternals->True` but this one does not.

Also `TracePrint[command]` is useful.

**Edit**

Actually, `TraceInternals` can be used here also. The trick is to apply this option to `Trace` itself and not to the command itself being traced!  Like this

```
Trace[NSum[((1/Pochhammer[m^2 + 1, m]) + (1/Pochhammer[m^2 + m + 1, 2 m])), 
          {m, 1, Infinity},WorkingPrecision -> 50], 
      TraceInternal -> True
     ]
```

Comment: Is there a way to discover the list of functions that do support `TraceInternals->True`?